# Terraform- GCP Data Proc Component Gateway Enable Issue

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-dataproc, terraform-provider-gcp

I’m trying to create data proc cluster in GCP using terraform resource google_dataproc_cluster. I would like to create Component gateway along with that. Upon seeing the documentation, it has been stated as to use the below snippet for creation:

```
cluster_config {
 endpoint_config {
 enable_http_port_access = "true"
 }
}
```

Upon running the terraform plan, i see the error as " Error: Unsupported block type". And also tried using the override_properties and in the GCP data proc, i could see that the property is enabled, but still the Gateway Component is disabled. Wanted to understand, is there an issue upon calling the one given in the Terraform documentation and also is there an alternate for me to use it what?

```
software_config {
image_version = "${var.image_version}"
override_properties = {
"dataproc:dataproc.allow.zero.workers" = "true"
"dataproc:dataproc.enable_component_gateway" = "true"
}
}
```

The below is the error while running the terraform apply.

```
Error: Unsupported block type
 
 on main.tf line 35, in resource "google_dataproc_cluster" "dataproc_cluster":
35:           endpoint_config {
 Blocks of type "endpoint_config" are not expected here.
```

RESOURCE BLOCK:

```
resource "google_dataproc_cluster" "dataproc_cluster" {
  name     = "${var.cluster_name}"
  region   = "${var.region}"
  graceful_decommission_timeout = "120s"
  labels =  "${var.labels}"
  

  cluster_config {
 
        staging_bucket        = "${var.staging_bucket}"
        /*endpoint_config {
               enable_http_port_access = "true"
        }*/
       
        software_config {
            image_version       = "${var.image_version}"
            override_properties = {
                "dataproc:dataproc.allow.zero.workers" = "true"
                "dataproc:dataproc.enable_component_gateway" = "true"  /* Has Been Added as part of Component Gateway Enabled which is already enabled in the endpoint_config*/
            }
        }
         gce_cluster_config {
         // network          = "${var.network}"
          subnetwork       = "${var.subnetwork}"
          zone                = "${var.zone}"
         //internal_ip_only    = true
          tags                = "${var.network_tags}"
          service_account_scopes = [
              "cloud-platform"
      ]
        }

        master_config {
            num_instances     = "${var.master_num_instances}"
            machine_type      = "${var.master_machine_type}"
            disk_config {
                boot_disk_type    = "${var.master_boot_disk_type}"
                boot_disk_size_gb = "${var.master_boot_disk_size_gb}"
                num_local_ssds    = "${var.master_num_local_ssds}"
            }
        }

       
  }
  
  depends_on = [google_storage_bucket.dataproc_cluster_storage_bucket]

  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    delete = "30m"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which provider version are you using?

Comment: I'm using hashicorp/google v4.29.0

Comment: Can you add the entire resource block that's causing the error to the question?

Comment: I have added the entire resource block in my question itself.

Comment: Ok, I see that `endpoint_config` is commented out, but if you want to use it you have to use the beta provider version, as the documentation says: `The endpoint_config block (Optional, Computed, Beta) supports: ...`

Comment: More info on how to set up the beta provider can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_versions#using-the-google-beta-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the snippet that worked for me to enable component gateway in GCP

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project     = "project_id"
}

resource "google_dataproc_cluster" "dataproc_cluster" {
  name     = "clustername"
  provider = google-beta 
  region   = us-east1
  graceful_decommission_timeout = "120s"
  

  cluster_config {
        endpoint_config {
               enable_http_port_access = "true"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is discussed in this [Git thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6422).

You can enable the component gateways in Cloud Dataproc by using `google-beta` provider in the Dataproc cluster and root configuration of terraform.

sample configuration:

```
  # Terraform configuration goes here

   provider "google-beta" {
   project = "my-project"
   
   }

  resource "google_dataproc_cluster" "mycluster" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name     = "mycluster"
  region   = "us-central1"
  graceful_decommission_timeout = "120s"
  labels = {
    foo = "bar"
  } 
  ...
  ...
  }
```

Comment: The provider that we give at the resource block  alone is not enough. You need to specify the provider  at the root section as well to make it work.